# Why doesn't C# volatile protect write-read reordering?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile

According to [this online book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx), the `volatile` keyword in C# does not protect against reordering Write operations followed by Read operations.  It gives this example in which both `a` and `b` can end up being set to `0`, despite `x` and `y` being `volatile`:

```
class IfYouThinkYouUnderstandVolatile
{
  volatile int x, y;
 
  void Test1()        // Executed on one thread
  {
    x = 1;            // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int a = y;        // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
    ...
  }
 
  void Test2()        // Executed on another thread
  {
    y = 1;            // Volatile write (release-fence)
    int b = x;        // Volatile read (acquire-fence)
    ...
  }
}
```

This seems to fit with what the specification says in 10.5.3:

> A read of a volatile field is called a volatile read. A volatile read has “acquire semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after it in the instruction sequence.
>
> A write of a volatile field is called a volatile write. A volatile write has “release semantics”; that is, it is guaranteed to happen after any memory references prior to the write instruction in the instruction sequence.

What is the reason for this?  Is there a use case in which we don't mind Write-Read operations being reordered?

Comment: my guess 1 thread is being started/scheduled slightly behind the other.

Comment: C# in a nutshell gives some information on this. Have to look up or Skeet is coming in here ;)

Comment: why do you think that the volatile keyword should synchronize threads? I thought volatile only prevented the compiler from optimizing away memory access to that variable.

Comment: If you need the guarantee, you can always use a `lock`.

Comment: @WouterH, I don't think it would synchronize threads - but it's easy to imagine that it would prevent reordering of operations involving `x` and `y`.  And in the example above, the only way both `a` and `b` could end up as `0` is if reordering was occurring.

Comment: WouterH: synchronized or not, it doesn't follow that if one thread runs, and then the other, neither one of `a` or `b` will be 1.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yeah I intend to use a `lock` in practice (because of this), but I'm curious as to why `volatile` doesn't prevent this type of reordering.

Comment: using `lock` `this` is an academic example of how to end up in deadlocks! be aware of that!

Comment: @MareInfinitus: it will never deadlock if you simply put a lock around these operations in each thread. One thread will just have to wait. In fact, these kind of operations NEED a lock :)

Comment: Albahari has a way of making these things sound simple: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_The_volatile_keyword.

Comment: Also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx

Comment: And http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2010/12/04/SayonaraVolatile.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Volatile does not guarantee reads and writes of independent volatile variables are not re-ordered, it only guarantees that reads get the most up-to-date value (non-cached). (reads and writes to a single variable are guaranteed to maintain order)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

> The system always reads the current value of a volatile object at the point it is requested, even if the previous instruction asked for a value from the same object. Also, the value of the object is written immediately on assignment.
>
> The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access. Using the volatile modifier ensures that one thread retrieves the most up-to-date value written by another thread.

Whenever you have multiple dependent operations, you need to use some other synchronization mechanism.  Usually use `lock`, it's easiest and only creates performance bottlenecks when abused or in very extreme situations.

Comment: "Volatile does not guarantee reads and writes are not re-ordered, it only guarantees that reads get the most up-to-date value (non-cached)." I don't think that's right. From the spec: "all threads will observe volatile writes performed by any other thread in the order they were performed" (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/q/10589565/ )

Comment: @MaxBarraclough Perhaps I should be clearer. Yes reads/writes of the same volatile variable are guaranteed sequential order. Independent read/write of two unrelated variables (i.e., the expressions don't count on each other as in OP example) don't have the same guarantee.

Comment: This is exactly why `lock`` should be used whenever code is referencing multiple shared values (which due to lock do not need to be volatile).

Answer (score 4):

Preventing `volatile write` with `volatile read` reordering will be quite expensive on x86/x64 arch. That's because of the write optimization called `store buffers`. 
Java went this way and volatile writes in Java are effectively full memory barriers at CPU instructions level.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe too late to answer ... but I was looking around and saw this. 
Volatile-read is actually a call to a method similar to the following:

```
public static int VolatileRead(ref int address)
{
    int num = address;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    return num;
}
```

And Volatile-write is like this:

```
public static int VolatileWrite(ref int address, int value)
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    adrdress = value;
}
```

The instruction `MemoryBarrier();` is the one preventing from reordering.`MemoryBarrier();` ensures that intructions before are executed before intructions after.
When VW then VR, you will have:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
adrdress = value; //this line may be reordered with the one bellow
int num = address;//this line may be reordered with the one above
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
return num;
```

Comment: As your answer illustrates, the answer to this question is actually quite simple: if anyone need sequentially consistency, one can always insert additional `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` where required.